# Hacer un join o relacion en Firebase y Angular2

Tags: firebase, typescript, angular4

Que tal amigos, tengo este siguiente problema, sucede que tengo 2 tablas en firebase las cuales me gustaría que compartan datos, este es matris de la db:

```
    clientes: {
        1: {
            nombre: "Juan";
            empresas: {
                emp1: true;
                emp2: true;
            }
        }

        2: {
            nombre: "Carlos";
            id_empresa: "emp2";
            empresas: {
                emp2: true;
            }
        }
    }
    empresas: {
        emp1: {
            nombre_empresa: "Empresa 1";   
        }
        emp2: {
            nombre_empresa: "Empresa 2";
        }
    }
```

Me gustaría saber como hacer una unión de estas tablas:
Este es el código pero aun no funciona, estoy en buen camino?:

```
getClientes () {
    return this.afoDatabase.list('/clientes')
        .map ( items => {
             return items.map ( item => {
               item.nombreEmpresa = this.afoDatabase.object('empresas' + item.$key + '/nombre')
                   .subscribe( data => {
                       return data;   
                   });
             });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple vista, tenes un problema en la segunda consulta

```
item.nombreEmpresa = this.afoDatabase.object('empresas' + item.$key + '/nombre')
```

El problema es que cuando pasa a generarse el string para el queryObject queda algo por el estilo

```
item.nombreEmpresa = this.afoDatabase.object('empresas1234asdfg123/nombre')
```

te falta agregar el `/` entre el string empresas y el del key quedando asi `item.nombreEmpresa = this.afoDatabase.object('empresas/' + item.$key + '/nombre')`

Y con eso no deberias tener ningun tipo de problema

Comment: Muchas gracias.